# How can I make the content response rely on multiple intents

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I know the question might sounds confusing, but basically my agent asks the user 3 yes-or-no questions and the user answer after each one, note that each question is an intent by itself, anyhow I managed to accomplish that successfully.

Now after the questions were asked and answered by the user, I want the agent to to give a final response, but it must be dependent on the answers which were given by the user..!

For example, if the user's answers were (yes-yes-no) then it gives a specific response and so on for each combination I set.!

Can this be done..!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with API.AI using follow-up intents. You will have to track the user responses for each matched intent in fulfillment and then provide a final response.